# uWSGI Segmentation Fault With Flask/Python App Behind Nginx After Running for ~24 hours

Tags: python, docker, nginx, segmentation-fault, uwsgi

## Problem

I have a [Python/Flask app](https://github.com/Justintime50/harvey) running in prod with uWSGI behind Nginx that deploys my personal projects via Docker. It works great for about `12-24 hours` when it suddenly starts `segfaulting`. The app accepts requests and starts a `Python thread` to deploy a project via Docker since it may take a couple minutes to do. We then immediately return a 200 via that endpoint to close out the request connection while the thread can continue executing the build and deploy.

I'm running the Nginx app via `Docker` (it accepts the requests and passes them to uWSGI via a socket). uWSGI and the Python app are running `bare-metal` on an `M1 Mac mini`.

- Python: `3.10`
- uWSGI: `2.0.21`
- flask: `2.*`
- requests: `2.*`

### Expected Result

This app should be able to run for weeks on end without manual intervention of restarting uwsgi every day. Segfaults shouldn't happen.

### Attempted Fixes

The only solution I've found is to restart uwsgi completely. I've tried dozens of config changes including timeouts, memory limits, restarting workers after X number of requests or time, and nothing can properly kill off the process and restart it after a segfault, let alone before it can happen.

### Project Config

Here is my `uwsgi.ini` file:

```ini
[uwsgi]
; uwsgi setup
master = true
auto-procname = true
procname-prefix = "harvey " ; space is important
strict = true
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
need-app = true
single-interpreter = true
enable-threads = true

; stats
stats = /tmp/harvey.stats
memory-report = true

; app setup
uwsgi-socket = 127.0.0.1:5000
module = wsgi:APP

; workers
processes = 3
reload-on-rss = 22 ; this is almost certainly a hack, seems to segfault at anything over 22mb?

; daemonization
daemonize = $(HOME)/harvey/logs/uwsgi.log
log-maxsize = 1000000 ; 1mb
```

Here is my `nginx.conf` file:

```ini
server {
    listen 80;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        # This uwsgi pass only works for Docker Desktop
        uwsgi_pass host.docker.internal:5000;
    }
}
```

### Segfault Output

```
!!! uWSGI process 76997 got Segmentation Fault !!!
*** backtrace of 76997 ***
0   uwsgi                               0x0000000102a2a09c uwsgi_backtrace + 52
1   uwsgi                               0x0000000102a2a5b0 uwsgi_segfault + 56
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001843802a4 _sigtramp + 56
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001841df900 _dispatch_apply_with_attr_f + 1096
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001841dfb48 dispatch_apply + 108
5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184557eb4 __103-[CFPrefsSearchListSource synchronouslySendSystemMessage:andUserMessage:andDirectMessage:replyHandler:]_block_invoke.52 + 132
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001843e7a40 CFPREFERENCES_IS_WAITING_FOR_SYSTEM_AND_USER_CFPREFSDS + 100
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001845570e4 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource synchronouslySendSystemMessage:andUserMessage:andDirectMessage:replyHandler:] + 232
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001843e6160 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_generationCountFromListOfSources:count:] + 232
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001843e5e6c -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_getDictionary:] + 468
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001843e59f0 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyValueForKey:] + 172
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001843e5924 -[CFPrefsSource copyValueForKey:] + 52
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001843e58d8 __76-[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:]_block_invoke + 32
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001843ddf8c __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 376
14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184558764 -[_CFXPreferences withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 384
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001843dd860 -[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:] + 168
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001843dd77c _CFPreferencesCopyAppValueWithContainerAndConfiguration + 112
17  SystemConfiguration                 0x0000000184fab8ec SCDynamicStoreCopyProxiesWithOptions + 180
18  _scproxy.cpython-310-darwin.so      0x0000000103703aa0 get_proxies + 28
19  Python                              0x000000010301cba8 cfunction_vectorcall_NOARGS + 96
20  Python                              0x00000001030c4cf8 call_function + 128
21  Python                              0x00000001030c2538 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 43144
22  Python                              0x00000001030b6a5c _PyEval_Vector + 376
23  Python                              0x00000001030c4cf8 call_function + 128
24  Python                              0x00000001030c2538 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 43144
25  Python                              0x00000001030b6a5c _PyEval_Vector + 376
26  Python                              0x00000001030c4cf8 call_function + 128
27  Python                              0x00000001030c2538 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 43144
28  Python                              0x00000001030b6a5c _PyEval_Vector + 376
29  Python                              0x0000000102fcaeac _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 96
30  Python                              0x0000000103040abc slot_tp_init + 196
31  Python                              0x0000000103038a8c type_call + 288
32  Python                              0x0000000102fcac44 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 136
33  Python                              0x00000001030c4d88 call_function + 272
34  Python                              0x00000001030c2538 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 43144
35  Python                              0x00000001030b6a5c _PyEval_Vector + 376
36  Python                              0x00000001030c4cf8 call_function + 128
37  Python                              0x00000001030c2538 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 43144
38  Python                              0x00000001030b6a5c _PyEval_Vector + 376
39  Python                              0x00000001030c4cf8 call_function + 128
40  Python                              0x00000001030c25c0 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 43280
41  Python                              0x00000001030b6a5c _PyEval_Vector + 376
42  Python                              0x0000000102fcdeb0 method_vectorcall + 124
43  Python                              0x00000001030c4cf8 call_function + 128
44  Python                              0x00000001030c25c0 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 43280
45  Python                              0x00000001030b6a5c _PyEval_Vector + 376
46  Python                              0x0000000102fcdeb0 method_vectorcall + 124
47  Python                              0x00000001030c4cf8 call_function + 128
48  Python                              0x00000001030c25c0 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 43280
49  Python                              0x00000001030b6a5c _PyEval_Vector + 376
50  Python                              0x0000000102fcdeb0 method_vectorcall + 124
51  Python                              0x00000001030c4cf8 call_function + 128
52  Python                              0x00000001030c25c0 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 43280
53  Python                              0x00000001030b6a5c _PyEval_Vector + 376
54  Python                              0x0000000102fcdeb0 method_vectorcall + 124
55  Python                              0x00000001030c4cf8 call_function + 128
56  Python                              0x00000001030c25c0 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 43280
57  Python                              0x00000001030b6a5c _PyEval_Vector + 376
58  Python                              0x0000000102fcdeb0 method_vectorcall + 124
59  Python                              0x00000001030c4cf8 call_function + 128
60  Python                              0x00000001030c25c0 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 43280
61  Python                              0x00000001030b6a5c _PyEval_Vector + 376
62  Python                              0x00000001030c4cf8 call_function + 128
63  Python                              0x00000001030c2510 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 43104
*** end of backtrace ***
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the solution to the problem, it appears to be specific to macOS which is where I'm running uwsgi. Per https://bugs.python.org/issue30385 and https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1722, it was suggested to add `os.environ["no_proxy"] = "*"` to the app. This removes the reliance on the macOS `CFPREFERENCES` which is ultimately what was causing the segfault. This may not be a perfect solution; however, it is working for my use-case. The app has been running for 5 days now uninterrupted when previously it couldn't make it 24 hours without segfaulting which shows promise and I have no need for a proxy.

Comment: I saw this same issue with gunicorn and uwsgi when trying to run a Flask API along with the `openai` library. When making requests to my endpoint which in turn called the OpenAI API, I was receiving signal 11 with gunicorn / segfault with uwsgi. I think you're right about CFPREFERENCES. Whereas gunicorn did not emit the stack trace, uwsgi did and saw numerous references to CFPREFERENCES_ in the backtrace.